# Rust: If &str is supposed to be a pointer to hardcoded binary than why can I make it mutable and change it during runtime?

Tags: string, rust, slice, borrow-checker

I am currently trying to understand the difference between &str, str, and String in Rust. I am very new to the programming language and have been banging my head on this for a while. I get the idea that String has a length and pointer that is stored on the stack and that the pointer points to some data on the heap, which contains the string data. I also get that it is stored on the heap because we don't know how much memory its string data will take up at runtime and therefore it can't be stored on the stack. For str, I understand that it is a hardcoded value in binary, which means that it must be immutable and that the only way we can get to it is with a reference: &str. If an &str must be immutable. Then why doesn't the following code result in a compiler error? Please help. I have been searching the internet and this website for hours now and I can't find an answer.

```
let mut s: &str = "foo";

s = "foobar";
```

Comment: In your example, there are two hardcoded values in the binary, `"foo"` and `"foobar"`. The assignment is just switching the stack-allocated `s` from pointing to one to pointing to the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `str` itself is immutable, but the `&str` is a reference to a string. When you do `s = "foobar"` you're making `s` point to a different string. Here's an example that should hopefully illustrate this... [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=57a70dcc1f9454a08607ebae5f9a52cf).

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut s: &str = "foo";
    let p = s;
    s = "foobar";
    println!("{:?}", p);
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

The [rust book on pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-00-smart-pointers.html) might also be a helpful resource to understanding pointers.

Answer (score 2):

In this example it's not the `str` that is mutable, it's the `&`.
`s` is storing a reference to some `str`, `s = "foobar"` stores a different reference to a different `str` at the same locaton `s`.
Note the difference from `let s: &mut str = "foobar"`, which would allow for mutating the string slice even though `s` is *not* marked as mutable.